# Why is Rails middleware overhead so high when nginx is used as a proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, curl, nginx

Thanks to Godfrey Chan for the helpful insights I got from him so far. He pointed me to the fact that there's a Rack middleware that will provide me more accurate timing about the whole Rails request in the X-Runtime HTTP header in the response, when compared to the reported time in the logs (Completed in XXXms...).

Here's what I get from my tests:

1 - Access the direct URL to the Rails action in Chrome:

- X-Runtime: 25ms
- Chrome "Waiting" time: 27ms
- Reported time in the Rails log format: Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.9ms | Sequel: 3.0ms)

2 - Access the same URL but using nginx with proxy_pass, also in Chrome:

- X-Runtime: 84ms
- Chrome "Waiting" time: 88ms
- Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 0.8ms | Sequel: 2.9ms)

3 - Copying the Curl address from Chrome's developer tool and running it with curl -I:

- X-Runtime: 105ms (sometimes it goes up to 400ms)
- Completed 200 OK in 88ms (Views: 2.0ms | Sequel: 5.5ms)

Those timings are pretty much consistent when I try them a lot of times.

Any ideas why Rails will take longer to serve the same request if it goes through nginx proxy_pass? I understand that Curl can't take advantage of features like keep-alive, but I believe nginx is able to get advantage of it. But anyway, the time to open a connection shouldn't be taken into account by X-Runtime header, right?

Comment: No significant difference for me, only about 4-10ms. Maybe you can share your nginx config?

Comment: After disabling some before filters (like Devise's authorize_user and some other for logging purposes) the nginx overhead was quite small... I'll try some more experiments later to see if I can trace down which before filter specifically is being affected by nginx and I'll post more details by then.

Comment: I don't understand. I've reenabled all filters back and I'm running the tests with curl -I -w %{time_connect}:%{time_starttransfer}:%{time_total}\\n plus the other params copied from Chrome and now I'm getting fast results, even with nginx in place. I don't see noticable difference anymore in using nginx or localhost:3000, so I think I should close this question as I can't reproduce it anymore...

Comment: just out of curiosity, now I'm getting around 10ms for X-Runtime, 7ms as Rails reported time and 13ms reported by nginx log and Curl.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how I should proceed... Should I vote for delete the question or should I answer my own question saying I can't replicate the issue anymore?

Comment: I think answering your own question is the way to go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143563/give-bounty-when-problem-cannot-be-reproduced

Comment: ok, thanks, will do that

Answer (score 0):

I can no longer reproduce this issue, so don't mind looking into it unless you can reproduce it yourself and provide us more details to investigate it.